# Can quantum entanglement be expressed in terms of knot theory?

Tags: entanglement, mathematics, resource-request, research

While writing [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9056) I was wondering whether the analogy of the nature of entanglement in the GHZ state with [Borromean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings) is more than a mere analogy (cf. [Aaronson's lecture](https://www.scottaaronson.com/qclec/10.pdf)).

The question in my mind basically is: can quantum entanglement, at least for the finite-dimensional cases, be expressed in terms of [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory)? Has there been any approach in this direction? If yes, then I suppose it would be a nice way to visualize qubit entanglements in various scenarios.

Comment: Could the well-known GHZ:Borromean Rings analogy somehow be related to the BQP-completeness of approximating the Jones polynomial of a knot?

Comment: Kauffman et al.'s papers appear relevant: [1](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/4/1/373/meta), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08047). Note: Jones polynomials and the ER=EPR hypothesis do seem to arise in this context, but I haven't read through the arguments yet.

Comment: Heh, there's another paper that says [Braiding Operators are Universal Quantum Gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401090).

Answer (score 2):

[In this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511096), the authors used Knot theory to define what they call 'Path Model Representation'. In a later section they convert this representation to qubits by switching to binary.